# Ansible include files in role

Tags: ansible

I have the below files.

```
../roles/requests/tasks/main.yml
../roles/requests/tasks/1.yml
../roles/requests/tasks/2.yml
../roles/requests/tasks/3.yml
```

In main.yml, I am trying to call other playbooks.

```
---

- name: Include tasks for requests
  import_tasks: "{{task_to_run}}.yml"


- name: Include tasks for adding 2
  import_tasks: 2.yml
  when: task_to_run == "2"
  tags: 2

- name: Include tasks for adding 3
  import_tasks: 3.yml
  when: task_to_run == "3"
  tags: 3
```

I gave the task_to_run in the tower survey and I got error as

> When using static imports, ensure that any variables used in their names are defined in vars/vars_files
>   or extra-vars passed in from the command line. Static imports cannot use variables from facts or inventory
>   sources like group or host vars.

So I passed it via extra-var and that part works but  tags is also not working, it checks only the when condition.

Any idea what is going wrong? Or is there any other option for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TLDR;

Integer tags should be casted to `string`, either as an individual value or as a list:

```
tags: "3"

# or

tags:
  - "3"

# or even

tags: "{{ 3 | string }}"

# ...
```

## The problem

Digging into the code needed to understand exactly why this happens but... from my immediate tests (ansible 2.9.4), `tags` is not playing well with `int` values.

Sample test file:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tags: # <see defs below for results>
  tasks: [{debug: msg=test}]
```

## Tag as a simple `int`

### Definition

```
tags: 3
```

### Results

All playbook calls fail with:

> ERROR! tags must be specified as a list

## Tag as an `int` in a `list`

### Definition

```
tags:
  - 3
```

### Results

The above error goes away but it is not possible to target the tag. Note that the result is the same calling with `--tags 3` or `--tags "3"`

```
$ ansible-playbook /tmp/play.yml --tags 3

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

## Tag as a `string`

### Definition

```
tags: "3"
# or
tags:
  - "3"
```

### Results

All works as expected.